# 301 redirect rule in web.config

Tags: windows, iis, web-config, http-status-code-301

I have a url http://example.com/abc/pqr/112-digital I want do 301 redirect to http://example.com/abc/pqr/digital

not working..

```
<rule name="RedirectToBlog140" stopProcessing="true"> 
 <match url="^abc/pqr/112-digital?$|^abc/pqr/112-digital(.*)$" /> 
 <conditions /> 
 <serverVariables /> 
 <action type="Redirect" url="abc/pqr/digital/{R:1}" /> 
 </rule>
```

Please Help

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your rule. You need to explain better what exactly is "not working".

Comment: When i set this rule in web.config then it does not  redirect to  http://example.com/abc/pqr/digital URL.

Comment: So it just stays on http://example.com/abc/pqr/112-digital, is that right? By any chance does that folder structure abc/pqr/112-digital physically exist?

Comment: Yes, it stays on  example.com/abc/pqr/112-digital.
Actually, this is Joomla site, and it is article

Comment: Do you have any other rules above this one that might be matching with stopProcessing="true"?

Comment: Yes, i have mention many other rules above this rule.

Comment: Put this rule at the top and see if it works.